# how to get value by split in vb.net 2005

Tags: vb.net, split

i have a database in one field like below 222-225. I try to make split to read that value for my function. Just simple function a=225 b=222 then total=(a-b)+1. here my code

```
Dgv.CellClick
'Dim x As Boolean
Dim a As Double
Dim total As Double

a = CDbl(Dgv.Item(8, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value)
Split(a, "-")
total = (a) - (a)
Dgv.Item(9, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value = total
```

My problem is this doesn't work. I can't get the value that I split. Any idea how to solve this problem?

note: I use VB.NET 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be this can help. try this...

```
Dim a As String
            a = ""
            Dim x As String
            Dim total As Double
            a = Dgv.Item(8, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString
            Dim ary() As String
            x = a
            ary = x.Split("-")
            total = CInt(ary(1)) - CInt(ary(0))

            Dgv.Item(9, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value = total
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `total=(a-b)+1` .. That should be

```
dim b = a.Split("-")

total = val(b(1)) - val(b(2)) + 1
```

Comment: still error"expression is not an array or a methode cann't have argument list"

Comment: @AndriansyahAndri .. there's some mistakes .. it's already updated

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, `Split()` returns a `String` array, like this:

```
Dim SplitValue() As String = Split(a, "-")
total = (CType(SplitValue(1), Double) - CType(SplitValue(0), Double)) + 1
```

Comment: Then your value has no "-" to split. Check that you are getting the correct value

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, the value you're looking for is 222-225, and that value is located in the specified cell of Dgv (which I'm guessing is a DataGridView).  If my understanding is correct, there are a couple of things going on.

First, I'm not sure why you're trying to convert that value to a double with the following line of code:

```
a = CDbl(Dgv.Item(8, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value)
```

The `Item` property of a DataGridView holds a `DataGridViewCell`, and the `Value` property of the `DataGridViewCell` returns an `Object`.  Trying to convert 222-225 to a double will, I believe, fail (though since this is VB.NET, it's possible it won't depending on the options you set - I'm not as familiar with VB.NET as I am with C#).

Even if it does successfully work (I'm not sure what the output would be), `Split` expects a string.  I would change that line of code to the following:

```
a = Dgv.Item(8, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString()
```

Now you have a string that you can use Split on.  The Split you have in your posted code appears to be the Visual Basic (pre-.NET) Split method [Split Function (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  As others have mentioned, Split returns an array of strings based on the delimiter.  In your code, you don't assign the result of Split to anything, so you have no way to get the values.

I would recommend using the .NET version of Split ([String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)) - there are several ways you can call `String.Split`, but for purposes of your code I'd use it like this:

```
Dim splits As String() = a.Split(New Char() { "-" })
```

Where a is the string value from the selected DataGridViewCell above.  This will give you a 2-element array:

```
splits(0) = "222"
splits(1) = "225"
```

The final part is your formula.  Since you have strings, you'll need to convert them to a numeric data type:

```
total = (CDbl(splits(1)) - CDbl(splits(0))) + 1
```

Which becomes (225 - 222) + 1 = 4.

Putting it altogether it would look something like this:

```
Dim a As String
Dim total As Double
Dim splits() As String

a = Dgv.Item(8, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value.ToString()

splits = a.Split(New Char() { "-" })

total = (CDbl(splits(1)) - CDbl(splits(0))) + 1

Dgv.Item(9, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value = total
```

Answer (score 0):

Split returns an array. something like this. VB.Net is not my primary language but this should help.

```
dim arr = a.Split(New Char (){"-"})
total = ctype(arr(0), double) - ctype(arr(1),double)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim aux() As String = a.Split("-"c)

total = CDbl(aux(0)) - CDbl(aux(1)) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a As string
Dim x As String
Dim total As Double

a = Dgv.Item(8, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value

Dim ary() As String
x = a

ary() = x.Split("-")
total = CInt(ary(1)) - CInt(ary(0))

Dgv.Item(9, Dgv.CurrentRow.Index).Value = total
```

Comment: error said "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
error"

Comment: Note that `ary() = x.Split("-") will not compile.